# how to change login/logout menu links dynamically in drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have created a menu in drupal 7 with Sign in link. It remains unchanged even when a user is logged in. How to change that to logout for authenticated users?

Answer (score 1):

I had to use 2 menus to overcome that. One menu for authenticated users and the other for anonymous. Then I user [menu_block](http://drupal.org/project/menu_block) contrib module to print out both menus in the same place based on user login status.

Hope you find this helpful... Muhammad.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it remained unchanged maybe because you gave an absolute url for sign in.
In order to create **Sign In** and **Logout** link in the same menu, please follow these steps.

1. For Sign In
   Menu link title : "Sign In"
   Path: "user/login"
2. For Logout
   Menu link title: "Logout"
   Path: "user/logout"

Now it should work like expected. Sign In link would be shown to anonymous users and Logout link would be shown to authenticated users.

For creating such menu items programmatically,

```
$item = array(
  'link_path' => 'user/login',
  'link_title' => t('Sign In'),
);
menu_link_save($item);
$item = array(
  'link_path' => 'user/logout',
  'link_title' => t('Logout'),
);
menu_link_save($item);
```

There are more options available that can be passed to menu_link_save, please check out [this link](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_link_save/7) to learn more about it.

Comment: How to programatically change the menu paths based on whether  the user is logged in or not?

Comment: Just add two links into the menu programmatically , Drupal would hide either of them depending on login status. Am editing my answer to enhance it for creating menu programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

By default core menu comes with user menu. It contains /user for the current logged user, but it doesn't show for anonymous access. to accomplish this you could:

1. Go to the user menu: admin/structure/menu/manage/user-menu.
2. Add a new link with the path: user/login.
3. Add the title you need.
4. Save

Look at [hook_menu implementation on user module](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_menu/7) for more details, but essentially it shows up only for anonymous users.

Hope this helps